# ShowWindowAsync not work in all case

Tags: c#

ShowWindowAsync won't work in all case. It works when I try it with notepad, task managger, or visual studio, it's just do the job, restore them when they minimized, but when I try it with windows explorer or another external process, it won't work. In all case, the GetProcessesByName find them, just won't come back from minimized.

PInvokeFunctions class

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(HandleRef hWnd, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr WindowHandle);
```

Method

```
public static void FocusProcess(string procName)
{
    Process[] objProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName);
    if (objProcesses.Length > 0)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        hWnd = objProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle;
        PInvokeFunctions.ShowWindowAsync(new HandleRef(null, hWnd), Constants.PInvokeConstants.SW_RESTORE); // SW_RESTORE = 9
        PInvokeFunctions.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is actually not possible. You are trying to find the 'main window' of a process and that is an non-existing concept. The topic is discussed at length here: [There can be more than one (or zero): Converting a process to a window](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080220-00/?p=23383)

> When you try to explain this to people, you sometimes get stuck in the Why won't you answer my question? cycle.
>
> "I have a thread ID. How do I get the corresponding window?"
>
> You can use the EnumThreadWindows function to get all the windows on the thread.
>
> "Yes, I know about EnumThreadWindows, but how do I get the window that I want?"
>
> Well, you haven't said what you wanted yet.
>
> "I want the window that corresponds to the thread."
>
> But which one? How will you decide among all the windows?
>
> "That's what I'm asking you!"
>
> But you haven't yet described what you want.
>
> "I want the window corresponding to the thread. Why won't you answer my question?"
>
> Note that saying, "I am looking for the top-level unowned window" is a step forward, but it still doesn't uniquely identify a window. There can be multiple top-level unowned windows in a process. For example, Explorer typically has lots of top-level unowned windows. There's the desktop, the taskbar, your open folder windows, and property sheets. If you ask for "the" top-level unowned window of Explorer, which one do you want?

And then Raymond ads the coup de grâce:

> Perhaps people are getting the idea that there is a way to uniquely specify "the" window for a process because the `System.Diagnostics.Process` object has a property called `MainWindowHandle`. The documentation for that property doesn't do anything to dispel the notion, either. I have no idea how that property decides among multiple top-level unowned windows.

So, as you see, you need to unask the question. What you want is fundamentally incorrect, since there is no 'main' window for a process like Chrome (remember, all modern browsers isolate browsing tabs in their own process). If you followed the discussion above, you'll know what to do.